# what is the name of the eslint rule to prevent empty lines after or before a curly brace?

Tags: javascript, eslint

What is the name of the eslint rule that will prevent empty lines after or before a curly brace ?

```
class Foo {
// prevent empty lines
bar() {
}
// prevent empty lines
}
```

Answer (score 4):

"padding-line-between-statements"

Details:
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/padding-line-between-statements

Answer (score 1):

The rule is "padded-blocks" and not "padding-line-between-statements"

More info : https://eslint.org/docs/rules/padded-blocks

Comment: Actually the "padding-line" rule is a lot more flexible and provides more control over the spacing than the "padded-blocks" rule imo.

Comment: hi @AdamReis but does it allow to consider braces as statements ?